# Apply JS range slider functionality to multiple ID-selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, range

**PROBLEM:**

I have four range sliders (from https://rangeslider.js.org) I wish to activate in my HTML document but I would like to avoid copying/pasting the same JS code four times. Is there a way to tell JS that I wish to apply this functionality for all sliders?

**BACKGROUND (HTML):**

- Each slider has three components
- 1) The first is where the actual slider will show up (**#judgementslider1**)

```html
<input id="judgementslider1" type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" value="50" labels="1, 100" data-rangeslider>
```

- 2) When someone slides the range slider an integer will show up (**#output1**)

```html
<output class="my-3" id="output1"></output>
```

- 3) Finally, the slider value is updated to a hidden input field (**#j1**)

```html
<input type="hidden" id="j1" name="j1" value="">
```

**QUESTION:**

How can I rewrite the JS code to take into consideration all sliders (#judgementslider1, #judgementslider2, #judgementslider3, #judgementslider4) and at the same time apply this numbering to output (#output1, #output2, #output3, #output4) and hidden input field (#j1, #j2, #j3, #j4)?

**MINIMAL WORKING EXAMPLE (MWE):**

https://codepen.io/constituo/pen/qzKOyW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

I have added a array of id's and looped it and passed to the function `valueOutput` to generate the `output` and set the `hidden` value.

Then I have added a `ids` attribute to that slider input.

then while on the change I got the target elements datas and passed to the function `valueOutput` to generate values.

```js
$(function() {
  var $document = $(document);
  var selector = [ 'judgementslider1', 'judgementslider2', 'judgementslider3', 'judgementslider4' ];
  /** * Example functionality to demonstrate a value feedback * and change the output's value. */
  function valueOutput(elem, i) {
    var element = $('#'+elem); 
    var value = element.val();
    var j = +i+1;
    var output = document.getElementById('output'+j);
    var input = document.getElementById('j'+j);
    output.innerHTML = value;
    input.value = value;
    element.rangeslider({
      polyfill: false
    });
  } 
  /** * Initial value output */
  for (var i = selector.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    valueOutput(selector[i], i);
  }; 
  /** * Update value output */
  $document.on('input', selector, function(e) {
    valueOutput(e.target.id,e.target.getAttribute('ids'));
  });
  /** * Initialize the elements */
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rangeslider.js.org/assets/rangeslider.js/dist/rangeslider.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rangeslider.js.org/assets/rangeslider.js/dist/rangeslider.css"/>

<form action="study.php" method="post" id="judgementevaluation">
    <ul>
        <h3 class="text-center mb-4"><strong>Morgonens Nyheter</strong></h3>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
            <div class="rangerleft col-md-3 col-xs-12 font-weight-bold">
                Very trustworthy
            </div>
            <div class="rangercenter col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <input id="judgementslider1" type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" value="50" labels="1, 100" data-rangeslider ids="0"><!-- added a extra arrribute ids here -->
            </div>
            <div class="rangerright col-md-3 col-xs-12 font-weight-bold">
                Not trustworthy
            </div>
        </div>
        <output class="my-3" id="output1"></output>
        <input type="hidden" id="j1" name="j1" value="">

        <h3 class="text-center mb-4"><strong>Andreas Berglund</strong></h3>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
            <div class="rangerleft col-md-3 col-xs-12 font-weight-bold">
                Very trustworthy
            </div>
            <div class="rangercenter col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <input id="judgementslider2" type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" value="50" labels="1, 100" data-rangeslider ids="1"><!-- added a extra arrribute ids here -->
            </div>
            <div class="rangerright col-md-3 col-xs-12 font-weight-bold">
                Not trustworthy
            </div>
        </div>
        <output class="my-3" id="output2"></output>
        <input type="hidden" id="j2" name="j2" value="">

        <h3 class="text-center mb-4"><strong>Sweden Television (SWET)</strong></h3>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
            <div class="rangerleft col-md-3 col-xs-12 font-weight-bold">
                Very trustworthy
            </div>
            <div class="rangercenter col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <input id="judgementslider3" type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" value="50" labels="1, 100" data-rangeslider ids="2"><!-- added a extra arrribute ids here -->
            </div>
            <div class="rangerright col-md-3 col-xs-12 font-weight-bold">
                Not trustworthy
            </div>
        </div>
        <output class="my-3" id="output3"></output>
        <input type="hidden" id="j3" name="j3" value="">

        <h3 class="text-center mb-4"><strong>Ewa Dubszanska</strong></h3>
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
            <div class="rangerleft col-md-3 col-xs-12 font-weight-bold">
                Very trustworthy
            </div>
            <div class="rangercenter col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <input id="judgementslider4" type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" value="50" labels="1, 100" data-rangeslider ids="3"><!-- added a extra arrribute ids here -->
            </div>
            <div class="rangerright col-md-3 col-xs-12 font-weight-bold">
                Not trustworthy
            </div>
        </div>
        <output class="my-3" id="output4"></output>
        <input type="hidden" id="j4" name="j4" value="">
    </ul>
    <button type="submit" name="evaluate" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: For some reason, when I copy the code into my project and range slider 2, 3 or 4 - only the output for range slider 1 changes. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok sorry, I missed to tell you that I added a extra attribute in HTML `slider input` called `ids`